# Can adobe air app be packaged to run on windows 8?

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air

I would like to submit an app to the Microsoft store , in the packaging options in flexbuilder I have androis ios or blackberry , however I was wondering if packaging my app as a regular air application would run on windows 8 tablets since it runs on desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For formal info, check out Adobe's [Flash Platform Roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html).

Yes, an AIR app can be packaged to run on Windows 8, but only in desktop mode.

Adobe currently has no plans to make AIR work in the "Windows 8 UI" / AKA Metro/Windows RT.  Previously the platform roadmap said AIR would be the way to make "metro" applications; however the most recent update reversed that.  It has been quite [controversial](https://plus.google.com/111010557165494466226/posts/HEr4m1eLZgC).

I think no support for AIR in "metro UI" mode means that uploading to the Microsoft Store is a no-go.