# Adobe AIR application development Windows 8

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have created an application for windows OS. Its working fine in XP,Vista and  windows 7.
Now My question is, Can  the same application work on Windows 8 ?.
Windows 8 has touch functionality,In my application I have implemented button events(Enter) and Mouse events(click) but have not implemented touch functionality.Do I need to extend the application or will it work without modification ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673811/can-adobe-air-app-be-packaged-to-run-on-windows-8

Comment: @RIAstar : Thanks. But i have asked  another question in the second part regards touch.

Comment: "Adobe currently has no plans to make AIR work in the "Windows 8 UI" / AKA Metro/Windows RT."

Comment: Your app should work fine with touch events on any platform including Windows 8; however you will not be able to package it up as a "Modern UI/Metro" app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it will work 100% right. WIndows 8 will play it, and also, touch events are converted to mouseevents - same way on android, etc..
You will still be able to push it to the appstore of windows 8, but ONLY with outer link to download, as it will count as a desktop app, not a windows rt / metro style app.